# Heroku being extremely slow when there's a lot of requests

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django app deployed to Heroku. A few days ago it was totally fine, when my traffic was low. I had 5 requests per second, and the response time was not more than 2 seconds.

However, I have recently started getting a lot of traffic. My requests per second have gone up to 50, and now my response time is 30 seconds. I'm trying to figure out whats going on.

Naturally I scaled up my dynos. I went from a Standard tier dyno to a professional dyno with 2 workers. I also updated my Procfile to have Gunicorn use 12 workers: `web: gunicorn wsgi -w 12 --timeout 30`

I also updated my database to a standard tier so I'd have more connections.

I realized I wasn't using Gzip compression with Django, so I added the Gzip middleware as well `'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware'`.

However, surprisingly, the request time is still 30 seconds or more. None of these new changes have made a difference.

I also optimized some of my database queries, and that had a very minor impact.

All this is leading me to think there's something wrong with either how my Django app is set up or Heroku itself, but I'm not sure where to even start debugging those problems.

Worth noting that running the app locally, or even in my staging environment with a hobby dyno and hobby postgres database, the app works totally fine since its not getting any traffic.

Comment: Did you solve this?